# subgroups of order 10 of a Group of order 30

Tags: group-theory

I have this group of order 30 that has a normal subgroup of order 7 such that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $S_{3}$. How can I find the number of subgroups of order 10 and figure out which one is normal.

Comment: The order of the subgroup needs to divide the order of the group. As $7\not\lvert30$, you got something wrong.

Comment: If $G$ is a group of order $30$ with a subgroup of order $7$, then the moon is made of cheese.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you mean the normal subgroup of order 5. Moreover, you can prove that the a group of order 30 has a normal 5-Sylow subgroup.

> A group of order 30 has a normal 5-Sylow subgroup.
>
> $|G|=2.3.5$
>
> The divisors of |G| are 1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30.
>
> Let $n_5$ be the number of 5-Sylow subgroup.
>
> $5|n_5−1  \Rightarrow n5=1, 6$
>
> $3|n_3−1 \Rightarrow n_3=1,10$
>
> $2|n_2−1 \Rightarrow n_2=1,3,5,15$.
>
> If possible let $n5=6$, then $G$ has at least $5.6−5=25$ elements of order 5. Consequently since $|G|=30$, $n_3=n_2=1$.
>
> Let $H_2$, $H_3$ be normal 2-Sylow  and 3-Sylow subgroups of $G$. Since $H_2H_3 \leq G$ and $H_2H_3=H1\times H2\cong H2\oplus H3$, $H_2H_3$ has 6 elements none of which is of order 5. Thus $G$ has at least 25+6=31 elements! So $n_5=1$.